# Set ggplot2 parameters to functions of inputdata in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, mean

I was wondering if the last part of the following scenario was possible:

```
data %>% filter(var1 > 4) %>% ggplot(aes(x = var1, fill = var2)) + geom_density() + xlim(mean(.var1))
```

So I wish to cutoff the x-axis at the average of the data which I am trying to plot. I tried a bunch of options to refer to the variable such as ".var1", ".$var1", "var1" but everytime when I try to run it, it gives me a warning that R can not find the object.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Normally it is possible, but you should try `data$var1`. It might not recognize the data in there. If this doesn't help, please provide sample data. EDIT: I think you have to give ggplot 2 values like `xlim(NA, 20)`, see the ggplot xlim documentation

Answer (score 0):

The `%>%` passes on your data to ggplot, but in additional layers you are not able to reference the variables using the `magrittr` way (e.g.: `.$var1`).

Try this:

```
data %>% 
        ggplot() + 
        aes(x = var1, fill = var2) +
        geom_density() +
        xlim(NA, mean(data$var1))
```

Comment: I notice now that I have left an essential part of the question out of it. I also apply some filtering on the original data. I have updated the question. Would the best solution just be to create a new filtered dataset and refer tot that dataset in the ggplot code? Such as 

`filt_data <- data %>% filter(var1 > 4)

filt_data %>%
        ggplot() + 
        aes(x = var1, fill = var2) +
        geom_density() +
        xlim(NA, mean(filt_data$var1))`